# how to refresh a webpage on updating in every browser that the page is open on?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

here is the scenario: I have two running browsers (Firefox and Chrome) and my page (index.php) is open on both. Now in Chrome I enter some values in the fileds (the code below) and with my mouse click on "Send" button, the content of the div#results changes using AJAX (in the browser that I was working with: Chrome) and we know that nothing would happen in firefox (the content of div#results in firefox would not change) but I'm looking for a way to do that! What should I do to make my code, shows fresh content in all browsers that have my page open on them, without making user to refresh the page to see the fresh content?

**index.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <h1>Just for test</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="show">
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
            <input type="text" name="age" id="age" />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send" id="send"/>
    </div>
    <div id="results"></div>
</div>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#send").on("click", function() {
        $.post("process.php", {name: $("#name").val(), age: $("#age").val()}, function(data) {
            $("#results").html($(data).filter("#res").text());
        });
    })
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**process.php:**

```
<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { ?>
    <div id="res"><?php echo $_POST["name"]. " And " . $_POST["age"]; ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Thank you so mush.

Comment: Checkout http://socket.io/ ... that's the way to go.

Comment: @Arash Naderi you can make an ajax call instead of refreshing the page.This call can be every five second or as you desire.

Comment: You should either use websockets with a server where all the clients connect and get the data from, or save the data somewhere in a server (database, file...) and make ajax requests every X seconds to sync the clients. Either way, you need a server to share the information amongst the clients.

Comment: @Claudio Bredfeldt: Thank you ;)

Comment: @Aleix: I think both approaches (especially making an AJAX request every X second) are not safe approaches because of incompatibility and runtime. But as it turns out, I have no other choices. thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to do that is to call your PHP server code every X seconds and verify if there a change :

JavaScript code :

```
<script>
    var updateHtml = function() {
        $.post(
            "process.php", 
            { name: $("#name").val(), age: $("#age").val() }, 
            function(data) {
                if(data.updated) { // if any change
                    $("#results").html(data.html);
                }
            },
            'json'
        );
    };


    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#send").on("click", updateHtml);

        setInterval(updateHtml, 15000); // update page block every 15 s if any change
    });
</script>
```

process.php

```
    <?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { 
    if(updated) { // write here your condition that says if there is any change
        echo json_encode(array(
                'updated' => true,
                'html' => '<div id="res">' . $_POST['name']. ' And ' . $_POST['age'] . '</div>';
        ));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('updated' => false));
    }
} ?>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: polling is horribly expensive. It would be better to use websockets and push the change.

Comment: Yes, it would be better. But Websocket is not **yet** a very strong technology that can be used in serious projects. Add to that the installation of third party soft and incompatibility with all used browsers.

Comment: Thank you Nabil, despite of the using extra resources and bandwidth I think I'll go with your suggestion. Thanks again.